# What real-world island did the Telmarines land on that took them to the Narnia world?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis

So this is all the information given by Aslan about this island:

> Many years ago in that world, in a deep sea of that world which is
> called the South Sea, a shipload of pirates was driven by storm on an
> island.

So it’s in the South Sea, which is the portion of the Pacific Ocean on the south of the equator. Does anyone have a suggestion for what real-world island it is?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What level of canonicity are you looking for?  Asking for "suggestions" isn't the best way to frame the question since we don't want people just throwing in random ideas without some basis.

Comment: There are thousands of islands in the South Sea

Comment: According to [this similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87833/how-did-the-telmarines-get-to-narnia) (with a more extensive quote), it was in the book Prince Caspian.

Comment: Balboa named the Pacific Ocean "the South Sea" because the part he saw was south of Panama.  Thus it is possible that Aslan used the term "the South Sea" for all of the Pacific, not just the parts south of the Equator, so you may have to consider islands north of the Pacific.  If the "many years" were before the date of publication on Earth, that would make it more likely that pirates would use the older term of "South Sea" for all of the Pacific Ocean.